# Terraform get ip address of api gatway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get the IP address of my API gateway with terraform. I can get the URL with "aws_api_gateway_deployment.api.invoke_url" but not the IP address which I need for my security group. I want to restrict the traffic, so my ec2 instance will only talk to my api gatway. Therefore I need the IP address to specify my ingress/egress rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API Gateway does not have a dedicated server with a dedicated IP address. You can't restrict the security group on your EC2 instance by IP in the way you want.

Instead you need to setup an [API Gateway VPC Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html), and restrict your EC2 instance to only accept traffic from within the VPC.